# How many Shared Libraries at max can we link it to a application in C and in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linker

I linked 14 libs and used the APIs present in the libs in my app. but when i run my application, i was getting into runtime errors saying 
"can't resolve symbol x in /lib/libxyz.so"

any idea?

Comment: Perhaps some of your libs need another library which you did not link? We could help more if you really gave the exact runtime error!!

Answer (score 3):

If there is a fixed limit, it is *way* above 16. For example:

```
$ ldd okteta | wc -l
66
```

and that application works just fine.

Your problem is likely that you built the executable against a different version of that library than the one it is runtime-linking to, and some symbols were changed (or removed) since.

Try rebuilding your application, or forcing it to link to the version you want (possibly by using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

I have a program `manydl.c` on [my web page](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) (for Linux) which generates some "random" C code into a "temporary" `*.c` file, compiles it to a `*.so` shared library, then `dlopen`-s that `*.so`, and repeat that many times. I was able to make it generate and `dlopen` about a hundred thousands `*.so` files.

You could read the comments, and try it (in a fresh directory, since it generates many  `*.c` and `*.so` files).

Essentially, **on Linux you can `dlopen` as many shared libraries as you wish**. The only limitation is the process address space (and also other memory resources), and you won't reach them before `dlopen`-ing many hundred thousands shared libraries.

And as [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8559446/841108) answered, there are some programs with many dozens of dynamic libraries linked in. My daily google chrome browser loads 73 shared libraries.

So in short, don't worry.

(It might happen that with a big lot of big libraries, notably in C++, you could get a significant startup time due to relocation & dynamic linking. But don't bother at first).